# When omitting "forall" are they really inserted before the statement automatically?

Tags: haskell, types

A lot of articles and books say that `forall` is explicitly added before the statement if it's not specified. For example

```
check :: (forall a. [a] -> Int) -> [b] -> [c] -> Bool
```

is actually

```
check :: forall b. forall c. (forall a. [a] -> Int) -> [b] -> [c] -> Bool
```

I have some problems with this because since Haskell uses currying I would imagine that the final signature would look like:

```
check :: (forall a. [a] -> Int) -> forall b. [b] -> forall c. [c] -> Bool
```

With added parens for clarity:

```
check :: (forall a. [a] -> Int) -> (forall b. [b] -> (forall c. [c] -> Bool))
```

And in this case the version with `forall` keywords before the expression seems to just be a shortcut for the convenience.

Am I right?

Comment: Haskell plays quite fast and loose with forall placement and ordering because type application is implicit (and gets erased anyway).

Comment: @DanielWagner: that's an interesting point, because while it's certainly true at the Haskell level, it's not true for GHC's intermediate languages (System Fc).  So `forall` treatment has to be at least somewhat principled, because it will be made explicit during the compilation pipeline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The nice thing about Haskell is that you can actually look at the intermediate language with the quantifiers explicit by passing `-ddump-simpl` to the compiler. As Tarmil pointed out, in System Fc rearranging the outer universal quantifiers in this function are semantically identical.

```
-- surface language
check :: (forall a. [a] -> Int) -> [b] -> [c] -> Bool
check = undefined

app1 = check undefined
app2 = check undefined undefined
app3 = check undefined undefined undefined
```

Translates to:

```
-- core language
check :: forall b c. (forall a. [a] -> Int) -> [b] -> [c] -> Bool
check = \ (@ b) (@ c) -> (undefined)

app1 :: forall b c. [b] -> [c] -> Bool
app1 = \ (@ b) (@ c) -> check (\ (@ a) -> undefined)

app2 :: forall c. [c] -> Bool
app2 = \ (@ c) -> check (\ (@ a) -> undefined) (undefined)

app3 :: Bool
app3 = check (\ (@ a) -> undefined) (undefined) (undefined)
```

Comment: Did you prettify and simplify the `-ddump-simpl` output by hand in the example?

Comment: This is with ``-ddump-simpl -dsuppress-idinfo -dsuppress-coercions -dsuppress-type-applications -dsuppress-uniques -dsuppress-module-prefixes``, though I did remove a few of the extraneous annotations as to not scare the OP too much.

Answer (score 9):

In fact, `forall a. (T -> U a)` is equivalent to `T -> (forall a. U a)`. So both you and the articles are right. The reason people use the former is that it makes it more visually obvious that this is a rank-1 type.